# VueJS, run e2e tests using Cypress into a Jenkins pipeline using a docker image

Tags: docker, vue.js, jenkins, e2e-testing

I created a VueJs project with some unit tests (using Jest) and integration tests using Cypress.

I have also a Jenkins pipeline in order to build, test and deploy the application.

I Integrated, as test stage, the unit tests but I would like to integrate also Cypress in order to run the integration tests into a dedicated pipeline step.

Is is possible to have this without installing any additional Cypress Jenkins plugin?

I mean, Is it possible to use a docker image to run the tests using Cypress?

Can you point me to some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [this](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/) with Jenkins [Docker capabilities.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#advanced-usage-with-scripted-pipeline) Also [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/Jenkinsfile) is another example you can refer to.